# How can I find the hollow cavities in a concrete block wall through stucco?

Tags: walls

I am going to install heavy wall cabinets to a stucco covered block wall. After much research, I decided that the best attachment would be with toggles (Snaptoggle). However, since stucco covers the block and hides it's outline, finding the hollow portion to insert the toggle is almost impossible without drilling a multitude of exploratory holes. Anybody have a better method for finding the hollow portion?

Comment: Once you find one, you have them all. Eight inch centers. Although, considering the relatively light load, I'd use flat-head Tapcons (or similar). Saves you the trouble of locating cells and requires much smaller holes.

Comment: Seconding the suggestion to just go with Tapcons. My very-heavily loaded cabinets have been held up with the flat-head Tapcons that @isherwood suggested (with a washer under each to spread the load in my case) for years.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for hollow cells, as opposed to filled reinforced cells, I'd use an infrared heat detector. It will expose both vertical and horizontal. (By the way, some concrete blocks are 12"...used as pilasters, etc.)